# RMarkdown CSS for single image, building slides

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I have the following code in Rmarkdown where I want to round the image tom.jpg. I am making a slide deck.

```
img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("img/tom.jpg")
````

I only want to round the image tom.jpg, but every image i create after calling the css gets rounded. How can i just round the image tom.jpg?

Comment: You are asking your CSS to apply `border-radius` on any `img` tag, one way to fix this is making a class `.rounded { border-radius: 50%; }` and setting your class to the image `<img class="rounded" src="img/tom.jpg"/>` - Marking this as comment as I imagine the class could be difficult to set in Rmarkdown, so it's only half of a solution

Comment: Look like it just need a prop `out.extra='class="border shadowed"`' source: `https://notes.peter-baumgartner.net/2021/05/07/images-in-rmarkdown-files/#summary`

Answer (score 0):

To add a specific class `out.extra='class="border shadowed"'`
[Source](https://notes.peter-baumgartner.net/2021/05/07/images-in-rmarkdown-files/#summary)

CSS:

```
.myimg {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

RMarkdown:

````
```
{r img-with-knitr, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', out.extra='class="myimg"'}
knitr::include_graphics("images/my-image.png")
```
````